# Z coordonate from intrinsic matrix and inverse disparity map in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, geometry, stereo-3d

I am facing the challenge to recover the Z coordinate from an inverse disparity map and the camera matrix K. The Z coordinate does not have to be metric but it has to be scale aware.

```
K = [[721, 0, 596],
     [0, 721, 149],
     [0, 0,     1]
```

I know that z=f*(T/d) where T is the distance between two co-planer cameras f is the focal length and d is the disparity. However, I am not told any extrinsic other than the camera is 1.5m up from the floor. The disparity is already an inverse disparity so I guess z=f*d? Also, what do I do with the other parameters in my K matrix (596, 149)? Is there any implementation in a library like OpenCV to recover the scale-aware 3D coordinates?

Comment: K is only from a single camera. What you need is the extrinsics from both cameras, or the motion of the camera, if you have a single camera. Since T is constant you could even  determine it rrom a single known distance&disparity in your image

Comment: Well, I am only provided with the disparity map but I am not told how it was obtained. Given that I am provided with a single K I think it was a single camera traversing through the space. However, I am not given any extrinsic but the height from the floor (1.5m). The reconstruction does not have to be accurate just scale-aware. I am a bit confused here

Comment: I dont think it's possible. Do you any clues in your scene, like object detections or something?

Comment: I know that they got the inverse disparity from the KITTI dataset.

Comment: If some monodepth approach is used you need to use T from the training, e.g. from KITTI setup stereo baseline.  But values wont be good if your setup differs much.

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. I will try to find the setup detail from KITTI. If you put that in an answer I will accept that.

Comment: I found that the cameras are 54cm and they are not rotated relative to each other. Does that help?

Comment: "instinct matrix"? did you mean "camera matrix"? feel free to edit your post.

Comment: "instinct" == "intrinsic" ? -- if so, please correct the title

Comment: disparity maps always come with the **distance between the two cameras** that were required to calculate these disparities. you need that distance. if you can't have it, you have to guess. it's a linear factor. maybe that's enough for your application. your `f = 721`. for disparity, you don't really need cx,cy (the third column of K)... well you do, if you want to throw these points back into space and you need to calculate the x and y coordinates too. z doesn't need cx,cy though.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz Thanks for your answer. If you could provide your answer either in python code or mathematical form that would be extremely helpful. Additionally, you could include the calculation for x and y coordinates too. I found that the distance between the two cameras is 54cm. If you post it as an answer I am more than happy to accept it. Thank you!

Comment: all of that can be found in textbooks, maybe in the documentation of OpenCV, probably in various blog posts and "tutorials" on the internet. I won't reproduce that here. I would recommend that you find some textbooks though. there's "multiple view geometry". Szeliski posts drafts of his book online for free. I'm sure he has a chapter on this stuff too. https://szeliski.org/Book/